# Utilizing biopython NcbitblastnCommandline to extract Nonsynonymous substitutions

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, blast

I'm trying to use NcbitblastnCommandline to blast a protein query against a nucleotide sequence, and then report the hit. The program ran without error. However, in the result, my query sequence turned out to contain XXXXXXXX instead of my input sequence. Anybody knows how to solve this?

The code I used is:

```
output=NcbitblastnCommandline(query=QUERY, subject=ALL_SUBJECTS, evalue=0.001, outfmt=5)()[0]
blast_result_record = NCBIXML.read(StringIO(output))
print(output)
```

my hsp_qseq output looks like this (a lot of XXXXX):
DTLIGVAITDGNQQIMLFSNEGKAIRFAETDVRAMGRTAKGVRGMRVSFASSTLXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXPETGEVLCASANGYGKRTPVNDFPTKKRGGKGVIAIKTSERNGELVGAVSIDETKELLLISDGGTLVRTRAAEVAMTGRNAQGVRLIRLSEEETLVGVVSIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXSEEAVSNNEDTSEE

While my QUERY actually looks like this:
DTLIGVAITDGNQQIMLFSNEGKAIRFAETDVRAMGRTAKGVRGMRVSFASSTLSEED
ADVENDDSDDNDDSADSSLVSRIVSLVVVPETGEVLCASANGYGKRTPVNDFPTKKRG
GKGVIAIKTSERNGELVGAVSIDETKELLLISDGGTLVRTRAAEVAMTGRNAQGVRLI
RLSEEETLVGVVSIEAVEDEEELLEGEVDTTETDSEEAVSNNEDTSEE

Did I mess up something?

Comment: I deleted my incorrect answer, but check for a soft_masking option and set it to False

Comment: Thank you for your input! However, it didn't seem to work so well. The masking is still there with the soft_masking option. I found a way to get the information I need eventually so this doesn't bother me so much now. I just want to report it in case someone/you are working on developing it. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you write an answer to your own question then, this will show you have solved the issue and help others if they have the same question in the future :) Also if something can be improved in Biopython, I can easily report it

Comment: My goal of the blast was to extract nonsynonymous substitutions, if the soft_masking worked, I could possibly use the hsp.query indexes to get SNP location; However, the blast results here not only had the masking, but also had gaps sometimes, which will affect reporting the original SNP location. Another problem associated with this tblastn was "max_target_seqs=1" sometimes gave me more than 1 results. I will post my way around it below in case someone else is interested in nonsynonymous substitution. But my code is a little messy - beginner

Answer (score 0):

my way around this to find nonsynonymous substitution after TBLASTN is below:

```
from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbitblastnCommandline
from io import StringIO
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio import SeqIO
import os
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio.Seq import MutableSeq

file="subject.fasta"
QUERY="query.fasta"
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(open(QUERY, mode='r'), 'fasta'):
    query_list = seq_record.seq
output=NcbitblastnCommandline(query=QUERY, subject=file, max_target_seqs=1, evalue=0.001,outfmt=5)()[0]
blast_result_record = NCBIXML.parse(StringIO(output))
count = 0
for blast_record in blast_result_record:
    for alignment in blast_record.alignments:
        for hsp in alignment.hsps:
            if count > 0: continue 
            count+=1
            mutation_list = []
            for index in range(len(hsp.match)):
                match_aa = hsp.match[index]
                str_match = MutableSeq(hsp.query[0:index])
                number_gap = str_match.count("-")
                index_in_query = index
                match_query = hsp.query[index]
                if number_gap > 0:
                    index_in_query = len(str_match) - number_gap
                if match_aa == " " or match_aa == "+":
                    if match_query == "-":
                        mutation = str(index_in_query + 1) + query_list[index_in_query] + 'ins' +  hsp.sbjct[index]
                    else:
                        mutation = str(index_in_query + 1) + query_list[index_in_query] + '>' +  hsp.sbjct[index]
                    mutation_list.append(mutation)
            print(mutation_list)
```